# UILabel not displaying user input text

Tags: ios, uilabel, line-breaks

I'm using a UILabel for displaying the user input. If the user input is like **"xxxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxx xxxx xxx xxx"** it is perfectly displayed on the UILabel. But when the input is something like **"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"** causes the issue. This text won't be displayed on the UILabel.

I'm using the following code for the UILabel functionality.

```
-(void)displayText:(NSString *)text
{
 UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75,50,30,50)];
 label.text = text;
 label.numberOfLines = 10;
 label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
 [self.view addSubview:label];
 [label release];
}
```

I have changed the line break mode to `UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap`,`UILineBreakModeClip`,`UILineBreakModeHeadTruncation`,`UILineBreakModeTailTruncation` and `UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation`. But the issue is still there. I know the issue is with the **input text with no spaces**, but how to fix this. Please help me to find a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "This text won't be displayed", do you mean that it's partially displayed / nothing at all?

Comment: @stavash: nothing at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text is bigger than the size of the label, you can either truncate it (head, middle, tail) or you can make the font smaller

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the height of your text first and then you need assign that height to you label.

and set numberOfLines = 0;

you can find the height from this function

```
 CGFloat height = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(yourlabel.frame.size.width - 10, 9999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `[self.view addSubview:label];` instead of `[self.view addSubView:label];`

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Here v is small letter not capital.

Comment: Got it. But if this were the problem, I think a crash would be involved. Probably just a type-o.

Comment: @PrasadG: sorry it was a type mistake.

Comment: I got answer . So check it 'text' is null or not?

Comment: @PrasadG: text is there. I checked that using NSLog

Comment: If u write NSLog in -(void)displayText:(NSString *)text, then OK. Increase label height to 100, you will get some difference.